# implement a singleton design pattern as a template

Tags: java, multithreading, design-patterns

Here is the question:

Implement a singleton design pattern as a template such that, for any given class
Foo, you can call Singleton::instance() and get a pointer to an instance of a singleton
of type Foo. Assume the existence of a class Lock which has acquire() and release()
methods. How could you make your implementation thread safe and exception safe?

My analysis:

as Joshua Bloch points out in "effective java", the better ways to implement 
    a singleton class is enum and public static factory method. Combining volatile
    and synchronized is the way I know to make it thread safe and lazy initialization 
    as follows

```
public class myS{
  private static volatile final _ins = null;
  private myS(){};
  public static myS getIns(){
    synchronized(){
      if(_ins==null) _ins = new myS();
    }
    return _ins;
  }
}
```

At this moment, I am a little confused to make a singleton template. My understanding is that we either have an interface with generic type or an abstract class. As long as the clients implement them, they are singleton. So, my guess solution is as follows:

```
public interface singleton<T>{
    public T instance();
}

public class Foo implements singleton<T>{
    private static volatile final Foo _ins = null;     

    public static Foo instance(){
        synchronized(this)         
             if(_ins==null){
                _ins = new Foo();
             }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Your `static instance()` method doesn't actually implement the interface's `instance()` method... This code and requirement doesn't make any sense. Rather look into the abstract factory and/or flyweight patterns.

Comment: And I'm pretty sure that this won't compile.

Comment: People keep trying to do this. While it does keep to Single Responsibility and keeps the Foo class testable, all consuming classes end up tightly coupled to Foo. Instead consider a DI/IoC Container framework.

Comment: If this is homework, please tag it as such. Otherwise, it might be worth sharing your motivations for why you would want to do this, as Singletons enforced by manual locking is... a bad idea.

Comment: How can some other class return an instance of a Singleton class?

Comment: @BalusC, can you give an example of applying abstract factory or flyweight resolving similar problems?

Answer (score 3):

The easiest way to get singleton functionality is to use a Dependancy Injection (DI) framework like [Spring](http://www.springsource.org/download).  There are plenty of other benefits gained by using DI as well.

Comment: Can you give a specific example?

Comment: `@Component public class Foo {}` is a singleton in a Spring container. As everyone else is saying, forget the Singleton [anti-pattern](http://www.google.com/search?q=singleton+antipattern). Use a DI framework if you care that much about instance/lifecycle management.

Answer (score 0):

'singleton' does not fit with 'template'. It is a kind of contradiction. If think you will be better off implementing `enums` as following

```
public enum MySingleton1 {

    ;

    public static void MethodA() { ... };

}

public enum MySingleton2 {

    ;

    public static int MethodB() { ... };

}
```

**EDIT**

A solution without enums would be:

```
public interface singletonMarker{};

public final class MySingleton1() extends singletonMarker {

    public static final MySingleton1 INSTANCE = new MySingleton1();

    private MySingleton1() {};

    public synchronized int mySyncMethod() { ... };

}
```

Usage

```
MySingleton1.INSTANCE.mySyncMethod();
```

The interface is only acting as marker, but it is not really necessary.

Comment: I think you are trying to use: public static MySingleton# Method(){}

Comment: @SecureFish no I don't, I am trying to illustrate how to implement the methods attached to each singleton.

Comment: you are saying using single-element enum class implementing singleton class. Then we accesss it through mysingleton1._instance instead of mySingleton.instance(), right?

Comment: @SecureFish No, I am saying: implement a different enum for each singleton you need. By trying to use an interface, you are exposing implementing object to all sorts of manipulations which break the singleton principles. Enums eliminate these issues. It is rock solid.

Comment: But how if not using single-element enum?

Comment: @SecureFish I have updated my answer, but really I don't recommend that method.